# Copy the a cell's text into the the next 4 rows down automatically for the entire excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big excel document with many rows.

The document is arranged by 2 main columns: ID and Year.
Each ID (Column A) has 5 Years associated to it in chronological order.

I need to filter different years by their key. For example I want to filter the year '1998' by the ID '311511'.

[image: The document example]

**The Problem:**
The ID column only appears on the first row of every 5 years series (as you can see in the picture attached). In other words, the ID only appears in rows with the year 2001 but is missing from the rest of the rows that contain the years 1997 to 2000.

As I mentioned earlier, it is a very big documents and to fix this manually (copy-paste, etc) is very prone to errors, not to mention the hard work.

Therefore, do you know of any way I could automatically copy the first row to the next 4 rows in the entire document? Some-kind of script or a function that automatically **take the value of the first row - like `311511` - and copy it the next 4 empty rows**, and after that continues to do the same for the next series - `311512` - and copy it to the next 4 empty rows.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming your IDs start in cell `A1` and there's nothing under the table.

```
Private Sub fill_with_id()

    Dim id As String
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 4
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Cells(i, 1) = id
        Else
            id = Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Will fill the table with IDs. Afterwards you can create a [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table) to create a data-summary of the table and the individual IDs.

> *Note: I'd recommend saving a copy of the document, as vba-changed document can't be reverted*

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Where and how I enter the code you wrote?